# Why am I recieving the error 'document.write can be a form of eval'?

Tags: javascript, eval, document.write

This is all I've got going, but my debugger says 'document.write can be a form of eval,' and my jsonString variable prints as undefined. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
function getUrlVars() {
        var map = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                                                 map[key] = value;
                                                 });
        return map;
    }

    var jsonString = getUrlVars()['json'];
    document.write(jsonString);
```

Comment: You've described what you have, but you haven't described what your requirements are.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What "de-bugger" throws an error for document.write? Or did you mean a linter?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15048239/798677

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason document.write can be a form of eval is because if you write a script element it will be evaluated.

As for why your jsonString is undefined, you probably don't have a parameter named 'json'.